# Delete to end of line in IntelliJ IDEA editor

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Does IntelliJ IDEA support this feature?

Eclipse supports this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>, vi with d$, so on...

Comment: pretty convenient for removing comments. My shortcut is set to `Cmd` + `Shift` + `Y`

Comment: Delete a line in jetbrains IDEs: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In `Settings` | `Keymap` find the **EditorDeleteToLineEnd** action, right click, assign a shortcut that you want (make a copy of the keymap as you can't modify the default one):

[image: delete to end of line]

Comment: already looked there more than once but for some reason I missed it. Thanks, again for your prompt reply

Comment: in mac they have set it to cmd + del

Comment: Seems now assigned to `Ctrl+.` and `Ctrl+,` by default. At least on my version of Idea

Comment: @javapowered No, not assigned to anything on my Windows 2020.1. 
I like to assign it to Ctrl+K like Emacs. Then 'Commit' to Ctrl + Shift + K or other.

Answer (score 26):

Here for Mac users, to delete the current line in intellij : [image]

source: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf

Comment: The OP requested delete to the end of line (from a given position.)

This is not pre-defined and you would need to define your own shortcut.

IDEA->Preferences->KeyMap->Editor Actions->Delete to end of line

Answer (score 14):

According to [the documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/basic-editing.html), it does not support what you want. You can only delete the whole line (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>) or delete to word start/end (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>).

Answer (score 9):

For Windows Users,

```
Ctrl + x
```

it deletes the whole line, except when you highlighted parts of the line

Comment: `Ctrl + x` 'cut's the whole line, i.e, it copies it to clipboard as well. Whereas `Ctrl + y` ***only*** deletes.

Answer (score 7):

To delete the whole line (for mac users):

```
⌘ + x
```

Comment: It's such a life saver

Comment: `Cmd + x` ***cut***s the whole line, whereas `Cmd + del` just deletes it

Answer (score 7):

For Windows or Linux User

```
Ctrl + y
```

For Mac User

```
Cmd + x or Cmd + del
```

You can also change this setting from Settings / Preferences >> Keymap >> Delete Line

Comment: `Cmd + x` ***cut***s the whole line, whereas `Cmd + del` just deletes it

Answer (score 3):

For me **Delete Line** was not predefined, I had to manually assign keyboard combo for it.

Go to **File->Settings->Keymap->Editor Actions->Delete Line**. Assign it as **Alt+D**.
 I'm using *Alt* instead of *Ctrl*, because Ctrl is already assigned with all the alphabets for different operation. You can also use a (Ctrl + Shift + ? ) combos.

Answer (score 0):

Beside assigning the new shortcut keyboard for EditorDeleteToLineEnd

My combination is: Shift + End (To select from the caret to the end of line), then Ctrl + C/V or Delete

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Y. The first time you press it you will get the prompt to set to delete the whole line or to use it as Redo

Comment: Before answering a question, check to make sure that the solution you provide hasn't already been given by someone else.

Answer (score -2):

double click to the line and keypress delete or backspace key